# syntax error for function-- missing parameter

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode6

I am learning swift from apple book. while writing code in xcode, I am getting error that parameter missing form function.

according to Apple code should be

```
func halfOpenRangeLength(start: Int, end: Int) -> Int {
            return end - start
        }
```

while calling this function :

```
println(halfOpenRangeLength(1, 10)) // According to Apple.
```

but when I type above line it says insert *end*

so this statement changes to

```
println(halfOpenRangeLength(1, end:10))
```

why this happens?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift always gives the first parameter a local parameter name and no external parameter name. This means you don't need to call it when you use the method.

After that, every parameter is given both a local and external parameter name. This is meant to be for clarity's sake. As Leonardo said, you can avoid having to name the second parameter by placing an underscore (_) in front of the parameter name.

In case you ever want to, you can also provide an external parameter name for the first variable by placing a hashtag (#) in front of the parameter name.

You can check out more information about this in Apple's Swift Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html

Answer (score 0):

use this instead I've checked it and it works

```
func halfOpenRangeLength(start: Int, end: Int) -> Int {
    return end - start
}
println("\(halfOpenRangeLength(1, 10))")
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. What if I need to store this result in variable like

var result:String = halfOpenRangeLength(1, 10));

BTW answer you suggested is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want it to require the argument name you just need to add _ in front of it and it will not bug you about it anymore:

```
                                    vv
func halfOpenRangeLength(start: Int, _ end: Int) -> Int {
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift gives automatic external names to parameters following these rules:

- **global functions**: no automatic external names
- **class/struct/enum methods**: automatic external names for all parameters but the first
- **initializers**: automatic external names for *all* parameters

That said, if it doesn't work in your case, requiring you to specify the external name for the 2nd parameter, than it probably means **you've declared that function as a class or struct method**, not as a global function.